# SVG transparent in chrome, works in other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, svg, postcss

I created a logo in Photoshop CC. Export As > SVG. Added to my project. It's referenced fine, as I can go to the path from the html in Chrome Dev Tools and see the SVG fine. But the icon refuses to show on the webpage. I've even tried importing the svg into Inkscape and reexporting it in different svg formats to see if that is the problem. Viewing the file in Chrome Dev Tools shows this:

[image: Transparent SVG]

I'm using [roots](https://github.com/jenius/roots), with [lost](https://github.com/corysimmons/lost).

#### jade

```
header
  .header-position
    h1.logo

    nav.navigation
      ul.links
        li: a(href="#quote") quote
        li: a(href="#projects") projects
        li: a(href="#contact") contact

    a(href="mailto:me@gmail.com").email-link +contact
```

#### stylus/lost

```
@import '_settings'

normalize-css()
base()

body
  padding: 0px
  background: #999

section
  lost-utility: clearfix;
  /*lost-utility: edit;*/
/*
div
  lost-column: 1/3;

*/
position-fixed(top bottom left)
  position fixed
  top top
  bottom bottom
  left left

.wrap
  display: flex
  min-height: 100vh

  @media (max-width: 775px)
    display: block

  header
    width: 135 px
    background: white
    padding: 30px 0


    .header-position
      position-fixed 0 0 0
      width: 135px
      display: flex
      flex-direction: column
      justify-content: space-between

  .navigation
    ul
      list-style: none
      margin: 20px 0
      padding: 0 20px 0 0
      text-align: right

      li
        margin-bottom: 10px

        &:last-child
          margin-bottom: 0

  .logo
    background-image: url(../img/CombinationMarkBottomText.svg)
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    background-position: center
    background-size: contain
    /*background-color: pink*/
    height: 200px
    max-width: 135px

  .email-link
    padding-right: 20px
    text-align: right

  .mobile-nav-toggle
    width 50px
    height 2px
    background #333

@media (max-width: 775px)
  .wrap header
    width: auto
    padding 20px

    .header-position
      width auto
      position: relative
      top auto
      bottom auto
      left auto
      flex-direction row
      align-items center

    .navigation,
    .email-link
      display none
    .logo
      height 20px
```

## Edit

Here is the code for the svg.

http://pastebin.com/UkGzVYp8

Comment: could you post your svg image? There could be some properties there that make it hidden.

Comment: I added the svg data, you can't upload svg to SO and there's like a 3000 character limit so I used pastebin.

Comment: That svg is a base 64 png image. Embeded in svg.... Don't do this. I would not even recommend just using base64 at all. So i would recommend to just use the png image. Or convert it to proper svg, not an svg with an png inside it.

Comment: ah, thank you. I exported from photoshop to SVG, so that's probably what did it. How were you able to tell it was png embedded in svg?

Comment: There is a image tag in your svg code. First give away. Second  `xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVB[...]` the xlink referes to a img/png data. When i convert png to svg i usually get Inkscape to convert them for me. That editor does have a decent png to svg converter built in.

Comment: sweet! I'll give that a try. If I've got the photoshop paths still saved is there any way to move those over to inkscape and export to svg from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You svg image: is a base64 converted png.

You can see it in the `<image>` tag attribute here: `xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVB[...]`

I would not recommend using base64 at all. Even more so in a image tag inside an svg image. (This is debatable and opinion based)

I would recomend using Inkscape to convert png images to svg. There is a build in function for converting in the editor. Its also free and a handy tool to have when working with svg images.